# How to get reference to a file inside a package

Tags: java, android, file, package

I have file kanji.xls.
I would like to get that file through new File();
What should I write inside that constructor?
I tried many options but didn't find correct answer...

[image]

I tried:

1. /kanji.xls
2. /Kanji database/kanji.xls
3. //Kanji database//kanji.xls
4. kanji.xls

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: sanbhat whole code is                 workBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("/kanji.xls")); I tried to put many things inside the File constructor, and I always get FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `assets` directory in your project to store this file and read file from there. [Android – Read file from Assets](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-file-from-assets/) will guide you.

if you don't wish to use `assets` directory,

Create directory as `Kanji_Database` instead of `Kanji database`. Then use below code.

```
File f= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Kanji_Database/", "kanji.xls");
```

Comment: your answer apears to be the best, but through assets I can only get a list of files or open a Stream. How can I use assets to get filepath that I can later use in new File()?

Comment: The files in the `assets` directory doesn't get unpacked. They are read directly from the `APK` ZIP file. So you have to extract to a byte array, write to a temp file and load that file.you can use `file:///android_asset/kanji.xls` for a url .

Comment: I managed to do it with assets like this: workBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(assetManager.open("kanji_short.xls")); Thank you for your help :) Just to be sure, all folders that I put into my package will exist in getApplicationContext().getPackageName()?

Comment: Could you also tell me physical location of Assets folder?

Comment: It is in inside of APK file. so there is no physical path of the assets folder in your app.you can use `file:///android_asset/kanji.xls` to refer your file in assets using `WebView`.

Comment: So I can't just locate it in my phone using Total Commander or similar application? Interesting. In that case resources folder could be better.

Comment: AFAIK you can't access `assets` folder via any file manager. if you want to get physical path to any file in your app, use resources folder.