# Android - How i can display an Excel table into a textview?

Tags: android, excel, datatable, textview

I'm new in Android world and of course in this community.
I'm searching a way to import my data table from excel file in a scrollable textview. Therefore, since I already tried  this html solution :

```
String htmlText = "html formatted text"

TextView htmlTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.html_text);
htmlTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
```

This solution is half-working.The html formatted code isn't displayed properly and the effort to translate every table (about 300 tables) in html code is too high.

I can't find any other good solution. Please give me some tips to do this stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890206/how-to-read-data-from-xls-excel-file-in-java-android

Comment: I'll try this solution...but it seems to be difficult to retrieve the correct table into textview automatically... Thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: And if you fix it, please answer your own question to help the next guy :)

Comment: I hope to fix it! I'll be happy to share the solution with the whole SO community :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem creating an Sqlite db containing the whole data set and then i displayed them with a custom listView .  The initial way no worth the work and the final solution is , of course, more smart and quick.