# Is there any other way to read .xlsx in Java than apache.org.poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache

I am working on a project and the task wants me to sort through 10,000 lines from an .xlsx file. I got it working with apache.org.poi jars but it is going extremely slow to just read the line and put it in an array. Is there any other way to read excel .xlsx files (that is quicker) that does not involve apache? Thank you

Comment: yes, you can check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16890299/2381006

Comment: I tried and got 'Unable to recognize OLE stream' error, looked it up and it only works with excel files created before 2000

Comment: If you're really brave, you can unzip the file and process the resulting to XML files yourself

Comment: Not that mad of a programmer like yourself