# how to read and write data present in excel file in assets folder to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

**How to read and write data present in excel file in asset folder to sqlite database in android**
   i have an excel file present in asset folder and i have to read that excel file and then write the data present in excel file into my sqlite database

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read data from XLS (Excel) file in java, android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890206/how-to-read-data-from-xls-excel-file-in-java-android)

Comment: the link you have given thats only read the data but how can i write the data into my sqlite database

Comment: just use dbhelper. do some research before post question in here

Comment: i have searched enough but couldnt find the proper answer .can you please help me into this.i will be very thankfull to you

Comment: You dont even have to search. Just read a lot of posts here with tag `sqlite`.