# How to import data from excel to google maps on Android?

Tags: android, excel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently trying to import Latitude and Longitude from excel to google maps using android studio but I can't seem to find any related tutorials. Most of them are javascript tutorial. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

there are two section

1)Read data from excel file using [How to read data from XLS (Excel) file [Java, Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890206/how-to-read-data-from-xls-excel-file-java-android)

2) Add readed data to map using 
[Add Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker)